# If $f$ strictly increasing and it is close to $0$ as $x\to a^+$, then $f(x)\neq 0$ for $x>a$.

Tags: real-analysis

Just like in the title. For the sake of simplicity, suppose that $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function statisfying the property $\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)=0$ and that $f$ is strictly increasing in its domain. Can we conclude that $f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$? If I draw a graph of the situation, the answer seems to be "yes". How to prove it formally? I hope it can be done without including continuity as an extra condition.

Since $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to a^+$, to each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in (a,a+\delta)$. How can I take it from here, when $f$ is assumed to be strictly increasing? Do I need to assume on the contrary that $f(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0\in (a,b)$? If yes, how then to obtain a contradiction?

Comment: For every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ on $(a,a+\delta)$. Remember that $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ is equivalent to $-\epsilon < f(x)<\epsilon$. In particular $-\epsilon<f(x)$ on $(a,a+\delta)$. Since $f$ is increasing, then this inequality is true on $(a,b)$ too. So, for all $\epsilon>0$, $f(x)>-\epsilon$ on $(a,b)$.

Comment: @user85667 Interesting. So, in your last line, how does it imply that $f(x)>0$ (or $\neq 0$)?

Comment: Since $f(x)>-\epsilon$ is for all $\epsilon$, this implies $f(x)\geq0$. The strict inequality is just by applying the condition of being strictly increasing: If $f(x)=0$ for some $x\in(a,b)$, then $f((a+x)/2)<f(x)=0$, but we know that $0\leq f((a+x)/2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)< 0$. As $f$ is strictly increasing, we have $f(x)<f(c)< 0$ for all $x\in(a,c)$. So the graph of $f$  in $(a,c)$ is strictly below the line $f(c)$. Taking limits, we get an absurd
$$0=\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f(x)\leq f(c)<0.$$

on the other hand, if there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=0$, then $f((a+c)/2)<0$ by monotonicity, and we fall into the first case.

Comment: Did you use squeeze theorem to conclude that $0\leq f(c)<0$ in your first paragraph in order to reach contradiction?

Comment: I've edited my question, i hope it is clear now. You could say that we're applying  "the upper bound part of the squeeze theorem" with the upper bound function been constant equal to $f(c)$.